# See data in gridview in ASP.net with Linq

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to show data in my database with Linq in gridview but I can't do it.

this Code :

```
var o = (from i in MDB.Messages
             select new { Subject = i.Subject, Message_Code = i.ID_Message, Question_date = i.Date, Question_Name = i.aspnet_Membership.aspnet_User.UserName });

    EndInboxGrv.DataSource = o;
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, if you don't enumerate an deferred operator, then you can't see any data, rather than a query. Please check out Deferred Execution in LINQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the grid

```
var o = (from i in MDB.Messages 
    select new {
     Subject = i.Subject,
     Message_Code = i.ID_Message,
     Question_date = i.Date,
     Question_Name = i.aspnet_Membership.aspnet_User.UserName 
       });
EndInboxGrv.DataSource = o;
EndInboxGrv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the variable o has data?

Did you bind it - EndInboxGrv.DataBind(); after the setting of the DataSource?

Answer (score 0):

you want to [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) the data to the gridview.Then only the datasource in the Gridview gets bind

e.g : `EndInboxGrv.DataBind()`

Read this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling databind on the gridview?  Unlike winforms you have to explicitly call DataBind() in asp.net.  I didn't see it in your code above, so if DataBind() call is missing you'd see nothing.

```
var o = (from i in MDB.Messages
             select new { Subject = i.Subject, Message_Code = i.ID_Message, Question_date = i.Date, Question_Name = i.aspnet_Membership.aspnet_User.UserName });

    EndInboxGrv.DataSource = o;
    EndInboxGrv.DataBind();
```